# How to configure Serverless VPC Access from Cloud Build "gradle test"?

Tags: testing, gradle, redis, google-cloud-build, google-vpc

I'm trying to put some integration tests in the Cloud Build process. So far I managed to connect to a MySQL server, but I can't connect to a Redis server since I can't add `--vpc-connector` option to `gradle test` command to configure Serverless VPC Connector.

This is part of `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gradle:6.8.3-jdk11'
    args:
      - 'test'
      - '--no-daemon'
      - '-i'
      - '--stacktrace'
    id: Test
    entrypoint: gradle
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
      - '--vpc-connector=$_SERVERLESS_VPC_CONNECTOR'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud

(... omitted ...)
```

Everything works fine If I remove the `Test` step. I need to add `--vpc-connector` option to `Test` step somehow to connect to the Redis server, but there is no such option in the `gradle:6.8.3-jdk11` image.

How to configure Serverless VPC Connector in the `Test` step so `gradle test` command can connect to the Redis server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing 2 concepts:

- Gradle is an application layer
- VPC Connector is an infrastructure component to bridge the serverless world managed by Google and the VPC of your current project.

So, Gradle absolutely don't care about the infrastructure: It will try to reach a private IP, the REDIS private IP.

Cloud Build doesn't support VPC connector and thus, you can't access private resources in your project through Cloud Build. (A [private preview](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/worker-pools) is ongoing to have Cloud Build worker directly in your VPC and thus not to have this VPC connectivity issue (because already in the VPC), but I haven't visibility on a public preview of this feature)

Comment: That's a shame. Maybe I'll install/run Redis in `Test` step or disable caching during tests. Thanks for the info!